# Mongoid saving documents despite invalid custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, associations, mongoid

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Mongoid or with the standard Rails validators, but documents that are invalid are still being saved to the database.

I have models set up to something like:

```
class League
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :teams

  validate do
    if teams.size > 12
      errors.add(:teams, 'too many teams')
    end
  end
end

class Team
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :league
end
```

I would expect the following test to pass, but it does not. Instead of my custom validation preventing more than 12 Teams from being added to a League, the league gets saved with 13 teams anyway.

```
# Factory for a League.
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :league do
  name "Test League"

  factory :league_with_teams do
    ignore do
      teams_count 5
    end

    after(:create) do |league, evaluator|
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:team, 
                              evaluator.teams_count, 
                              league: league)
    end
  end
end

describe League do
  it "should not allow more than 12 teams" do
    league = FactoryGirl.create(:league_with_teams, teams_count: 12)
    league.teams << FactoryGirl.create(:team)
    league.should_not be_valid # passes
    League.find(league.id).teams.size.should eq(12) # fails
  end
end
```

The funny thing is, if I change the line in the test which adds the 13th team to use build instead of create, `league.teams << FactoryGirl.build(:team)`, then the test passes. However this is not a solution because I want to guarantee that a League cannot have more than 12 teams regardless of whether or not the teams being added are new or already in the DB.

Is there anyway to guarantee this?

**Edit**

Adding a validator to the Team model, like I did below, doesn't seem to work either.

```
class Team
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :league

  validate do |team|
    if league.teams.size > 12
      errors.add :base, "cannot have more than 12 teams in a league"
    end
  end
end
```

I believe the problem has to do with the fact that `<<` and `push` are atomic operations, and therefore they skip callbacks and validations. That being said, this must be a fairly common usecase, no? So how are other people validating the number of documents being referenced?

Comment: the validation should be in team

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: what did you do exactly?

Comment: ok, got it. Replace `league.teams << FactoryGirl.create(:team)` with `league.teams.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:team))`

Comment: And what if I want to add a Team that already exists to a League? The validation won't happen and I could exceed 12 teams.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the problem is with `<<` or `push` methods because them both should trigger model's validations.

Try using:

`league.teams << FactoryGirl.create(:team, league: league)`

Comment: I ended up having to use the after_add and before_add callbacks of the master branch of mongoid to get this to work. The atomic push methods don't perform validations.